# apache rewrite rule not working as expected

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

Below is my `.htaccess` code:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName api.xxxx.com
        DocumentRoot /dianxiaoer/html/two-twenty
         <Directory /dianxiaoer/html/two-twenty>
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteRule . index.php
                RewriteRule /notify/alipay /mobile/index.php?act=notify&op=alipay
                #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
         </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

URL rewriting rule

```
api.xxxx.com/notify/alipay to api.xxxx.com/mobile/index.php?act=notify&op=alipay
```

is not working correctly. Can anyone please explain what am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The ninth line of code does not work and can not be redirected

Comment: Probably because line 8 rule is overriding it

Comment: Added more explanation and made formatting changes

Answer (score 0):

This line, `RewriteRule . index.php` will override anything that comes after it.

If you put that one at the end then it should sort out your issue.

Try swapping line 8 and 9 like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName api.xxxx.com
        DocumentRoot /dianxiaoer/html/two-twenty
        <Directory /dianxiaoer/html/two-twenty>
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteRule /notify/alipay /mobile/index.php?act=notify&op=alipay [L]
                RewriteRule . index.php
                #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
         </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hopefully that solves your issue.